# How can I correctly print out data to a webpage using json_encode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a button on my wepbage that will display data from a db using `ajax`, so the page does not have to be refreshed. When I click the button and view source and go to my network tab, the data is showing correctly as it should but there is nothing actually echoing out to the page. Here is my relevant `getItem.php`. Here my php code:

```
mysqli_select_db($con,"items");
$sql="SELECT * FROM items";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    $rows[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);

echo json_encode($rows);
//echo json_last_error();
```

and button `click` jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#button1').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getItem.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg.success) {
                $("#responsecontainer").html(msg);
            } else {
                alert("error");

        }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a syntax error? Looks like you're forgetting a closing bracket after the else statement.

Comment: i noticed that and fixed, still the same unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

With the if statement you're checking if `msg.success` is true, but you tell the ajax call that the `dataType` returned should be in html form so it's comparing undefined values, based on the code that you provided I think what you're rather looking for is something like this.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getItem.php",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#responsecontainer").html(msg);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
});
```

Still, if you want to do something with the data from the success function you will need to [parse it](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) or change `dataType: "html",` to `dataType: "json",`.